# Magento 2 Minicart content not displaying

Tags: magento2, cart, knockoutjs, mini-cart, custom-template

I'm working on developing my own theme by extending the Magento Blank theme.

I'm trying to add the minicart to my `header.phtml` file.

I'm loading the minicart in my header like so:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()
      ->createBlock('Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar')
      ->setTemplate('Magento_Checkout::cart/minicart.phtml')
      ->toHtml(); ?>
```

The minicart shows on the frontend, but does not load the content, see link:
https://prnt.sc/mrrgli

Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

**first we have to override web/template files to our magento theme file, in my case content.html**

```
Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/content.html
```

**After changes in content.html file, we have to deploy static file using command**

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

OR

You have to delete content.html(i have to change content in this file) file from `pub/static/frontend/Magento/buytea/en_US/Magento_Checkout/template/minicart` and reload page again.

Comment: I have the 'Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/content.html' saved under my theme, I ran a 'static-content:deploy' but the source shows the content template isn't being loaded still